# How to use Firebase Point-in-time recovery (PITR)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, backups, pitr, point-in-time-recovery

I have just read the docs on the new [Point-in-time recovery (PITR)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pitr) release which I am absolutely pumped about.

I’m trying to test out the sample code [provided by Firebase here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-pitr) for reading a PITR version and can’t get it to work. I have enabled PITR on my Firebase project as instructed in the docs & I’m on the latest version of `firebase-admin` from NPM.

The code I am using is as follows:

```js
const documentRef = firestore.collection("users").doc("zqN5sVLtCSUkTJqmC64Nsv9mKYD2");

const preUpdate = 1691218778;
const postUpdate = 1691226145;

const timeToUse = preUpdate;

const documentSnapshot = await firestore.runTransaction(
    updateFunction => updateFunction.get(documentRef),
    { readOnly: true, readTime: new Timestamp(timeToUse, 0) }
);

console.log(`Email address at ${moment(timeToUse).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")} was ${documentSnapshot.data().email}`)
```

The error that I am getting back from Firestore is as follows:

```js
"error": {
        "code": 3,
        "details": "Invalid transaction.",
        "metadata": {
            "internalRepr": {},
            "options": {}
        },
        "note": "Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient"
    }
```

Any help / guidance from anyone who has managed to test out PITR would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved thanks to [MarkDuckworth on GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/1877). The issue seemed to be related to the timestamps being used not being perfectly aligned to minute granularity. The below code worked as expected.

```js
const ref = firestore.collection("users").doc("zqN5sVLtCSUkTJqmC64Nsv9mKYD2");

  const readTimestamp = Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.parse('2023-08-10T12:31:00Z'));

  console.log(`PITR READ FOR {${readTimestamp.toMillis()} | ${readTimestamp.toDate().toISOString()}}`);

  const querySnapshot = await firestore.runTransaction(
    updateFunction => updateFunction.get(ref),
    { readOnly: true, readTime: readTimestamp }
  );

  console.log(querySnapshot.data()?.email);
```